# Need to run Pyspark jobs in local mode and connect S3 inside Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

I wanted to run pyspark jobs in local mode inside Sagemaker Studio.

From what I have known of official docs we need access_key and secret_key [to connect with S3.](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-spark/tree/master/sagemaker-pyspark-sdk)

I was planning to get credentials using botocore by the below script. But its secret_key and value doesn't work in pyspark nor in python.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
access_key = credentials.access_key
secret_key = credentials.secret_key

// does not work
```

For pyspark

```
import sagemaker_pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

classpath = ":".join(sagemaker_pyspark.classpath_jars())
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", classpath) \
.config("fs.s3a.access.key", credentials.access_key) \
.config("fs.s3a.secret.key",credentials.secret_key).getOrCreate()

// does not work
```

```
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=credentials.access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key)
// doesn not work
```

however, if i don't provide credentials it works

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
# works
```

I wanted to know how boto3 can connect with S3 without credentials and how to get them so that I can provide those credentials to pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

1. SageMaker Studio notebooks have an execution role associated with it. So, `s3_client = boto3.client("s3")` will work as-is, since it's assuming the notebooks' execution role.
2. If you prefer to extract the access and secret key from the role and then use them to access S3, you'll need to pass the token as well. Like this -

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials.access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key,
    aws_session_token=credentials.token
)
```

Also, based on your use case, I'll also recommend looking at universal notebooks for Studio, see blog here - [Create and manage Amazon EMR Clusters from SageMaker Studio to run interactive Spark and ML workloads – Part 1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/part-1-create-and-manage-amazon-emr-clusters-from-sagemaker-studio-to-run-interactive-spark-and-ml-workloads/).